# page redirect not working on landing page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have reposted this as problem never got solved due to administrator moving the post as a wiki Page as there was an easy typo which thought to be the problem in the PHP file but that isn't what is causing the problem.

Please could you help in me being able redirecting to a thank you page.
I have tried numerous redirects in Javascript and PHP file but Can't seem to figure it out.

When i click the submit button the email details get sent perfectly but the page will not redirect.

Thanks in advance

Adam

```js
  /* ==================================
    Hero Form Validation
 =====================================*/
 $('#hero-submit').click(function(e){

        // Stop form submission & check the validation
        e.preventDefault();

        // Variable declaration
        var error = false;
        var fname = $('#hero-fname').val();
        var email = $('#hero-email').val();
        var username = $('#hero-username').val();

      // Form field validation
        if(fname.length == 0){
            var error = true;
            $('#hero-fname').parent('div').addClass('field-error');
        }else{
            $('#hero-fname').parent('div').removeClass('field-error');
        }
        if(email.length == 0 || email.indexOf('@') == '-1'){
            var error = true;
            $('#hero-email').parent('div').addClass('field-error');
        }else{
            $('#hero-email').parent('div').removeClass('field-error');
        }
        if(username.length == 0){
            var error = true;
            $('#hero-username').parent('div').addClass('field-error');
        }else{
            $('#hero-username').parent('div').removeClass('field-error');
        }

         if(error == true){
         $('#hero-error-notification').addClass('show-up');
        }else{
           $('#hero-error-notification').removeClass('show-up');
        }

        if(error == false){
            $.post("hero-form.php", $("#register-form").serialize(),function(result){
                if(result == 'sent'){
                    window.location.replace("http://SOMESITE.COM/ppi/page2.html");
     $('#hero-success-notification').addClass('show-up');
                    $('#hero-submit').addClass('disabled');
                }
            });
        }
    });


 // Function to close the Notification
    $('a.notification-close').click(function(){
     $(this).parent('div').fadeOut(200);
    });
```

```css
<?php
$subject = 'Register New Account on Urip Landing Page'; // Subject of your email
$to = 'TO-EMAIL@DOMAIN.COM';  //Recipient's or Your E-mail

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: " . $_REQUEST['email'] . "\r\n"; // Sender's E-mail
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$message  = 'ACCOUNT DETAILS: ' . "<br>";
$message .= 'Username: ' . $_REQUEST['username'] . "<br>";
$message .= 'First Name: ' . $_REQUEST['fname'] . "<br>";
$message .= 'Last Name: ' . $_REQUEST['lname'] . "<br>";
$message .= 'Email Address: ' . $_REQUEST['email'] . "<br>";
$message .= 'Phone Number: ' . $_REQUEST['phone'];

////// Redirect user after submitting form  
$redirect_thankyou = 'http://SOMESITE.COM/ppi/page2.html';  
$redirect_error = 'http://SOMESITE.COM/ppi/page3.html';   

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    header("Location: $redirect_thankyou"); 
    exit(); 
} 
else 
{ 
    header("Location: $redirect_error"); 
    exit(); 
} 

?>
```

```html
<!--DOCTYPE html -->
<html><head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

     <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,400italic|Montserrat:700,400|Varela+Round">

  <!-- Font Icon -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/icomoon/icomoon.css">

  <!-- Swipebox -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/swipebox.css">

  <!-- Animate CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">

  <!-- Slick CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/slick/slick.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/slick/slick-theme.css">

  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-v2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-responsive-v2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/expandableGallery.css">

     <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
     <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
       <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
     <![endif]-->
     <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->

   </head>

 <body>

     <div id="page" class="page main">



     <!--
   ==========================
   == BEGIN HEADER CONTENT ==
   ==========================
   -->
     <header id="main-header" class="the-header the-origin-header">

    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-12">

       <a href="#0" class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Urip Logo" style="outline: none; cursor: inherit;"></a> <!-- Your Logo -->

       <a href="#0" id="nav-menu-trigger" class="menu-toggle pull-right all-caps">Menu<span class="icon-menu5"></span></a> <!-- Menu Toggle -->

      </div> <!--/ .col-lg-12 -->

     </div> <!--/ .row -->
    </div> <!--/ .container -->

     </header>
     <!--
   =========================
   ==/ END HEADER CONTENT ==
   =========================
   -->


   <!--
   ============================
   == BEGIN NAV MENU CONTENT ==
   ============================
   -->
   <nav id="nav-wrapper">

    <a class="nav-close" href="#0" style="outline: none; cursor: inherit;"><span class="icon-cross2"></span></a>

    <ul id="main-nav" class="main-nav all-caps">
     <li class="current"><a href="#hero" style="outline: none; cursor: inherit;">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#what-we-do" style="outline: none; cursor: inherit;">What We Do</a></li>
     <li><a href="#our-features" style="outline: none; cursor: inherit;">Our Features</a></li>
     <li><a href="#pricing" style="outline: none; cursor: inherit;">Pricing</a></li>
     <li><a href="#our-team" style="outline: none; cursor: inherit;">The Team</a></li>
     <li><a href="#customer-story" style="outline: none; cursor: inherit;">Customers</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="external" href="#0" style="outline: none; cursor: inherit;">
       Dropdown
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#0" style="outline: none; cursor: inherit;">Some Submenu</a></li>
       <li><a href="#0" style="outline: none; cursor: inherit;">And More</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul> <!--/ .main-nav -->

    <ul class="secondary-nav">
     <li><a href="#0" style="outline: none; cursor: inherit;">About This Template</a></li>
     <li><a href="#0" style="outline: none; cursor: inherit;">Privacy Policy</a></li>
     <li><a href="#0" style="outline: none; cursor: inherit;">Terms of Service</a></li>
     <li><a href="#0" style="outline: none; cursor: inherit;">Legal</a></li>
     <li><a href="#0" style="outline: none; cursor: inherit;">Careers</a></li>
     <li><a class="contact-trigger" style="outline: none; cursor: inherit;">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul> <!--/ .secondary-nav -->

   </nav>
   <!--
   ===========================
   ==/ END NAV MENU CONTENT ==
   ===========================
   -->


   <!--
   ========================
   == BEGIN MAIN CONTENT ==
   ========================
   -->

    <!--
    ========================
    == BEGIN HERO SECTION ==
    ========================
    -->
    <section id="hero" class="hero-form-layout breaking" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" data-stellar-vertical-offset="50" style="background-position: 50% 0px;">

     <div class="hero-split-right"></div>

     <div class="container">

      <div class="vertical-center-wrapper">
       <div class="vertical-center-table">
        <div class="vertical-center-content">

         <!-- BEGIN Hero Content -->
         <div class="hero-content row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 margin-top-40">

           <div class="editContent" style="outline: none; cursor: inherit;">
            <p class="lead zero-bottom text-shadow-xsmall">Meet Urip Landing Page Template</p>
           </div>

           <div class="editContent" style="outline: none; cursor: inherit;">
            <h2 class="text-shadow-medium">All in One Landing Page that Converts</h2>
           </div>

           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10">

             <div class="videoWrapper embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">

              <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/93094247?color=19a9e5&amp;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="470" height="265" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
              

             </div> <!--/ .embed-responsive -->

            </div>
           </div> <!--/ .row -->

          </div> <!--/ .col-lg-6 -->

          <div class="hero-form-wrapper col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-6 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 centered">

           <div class="editContent">
            <h4 class="all-caps margin-bot-15">Create Account for Free</h4>
           </div>

           <div class="editContent">
            <p class="zero-bottom">
            Create account in 30 seconds. No credit card required.<br>
            Already have an account? <a href="#0" class="more" style="outline: none; cursor: inherit;">Log in here.</a>
            </p>
           </div>

           <form class="register-form margin-top-32 margin-bot-5" id="register-form"  method="post">
            <div class="row">

             <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
              <div class="required-field">
               <input name="fname" id="hero-fname" class="hero-input" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
              </div> <!--/ .required-field -->
             </div>

             <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
              <input name="lname" id="hero-lname" class="hero-input" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
             </div>

             <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
              <div class="required-field">
               <input name="username" id="hero-username" class="hero-input" type="text" placeholder="Choose Username">
              </div> <!--/ .required-field -->
             </div>

             <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
              <div class="required-field">
               <input name="email" id="hero-email" class="hero-input" type="text" placeholder="Email Address">
              </div> <!--/ .required-field -->
             </div>

             <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
              <input name="phone" id="hero-phone" class="hero-input" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number">
             </div>

             <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                                                    
              <button id="hero-submit" type="submit" class="submit-btn">Create</button>
             </div>

            </div>
           </form> <!--/ .register-form -->

           <div class="editContent" style="outline: none; cursor: inherit;">
            <p class="zero-bottom">By creating account, you agree to the <a href="#0" class="more" style="outline: none; cursor: inherit;">Terms of Service</a></p>
           </div>

          </div> <!--/ .hero-form-wrapper -->

         </div> <!--/ .row -->
         <!-- END Hero Content -->

        </div> <!--/ .vertical-center-content -->
       </div> <!--/ .vertical-center-table -->
      </div> <!-- / .vertical-center-wrapper -->

     </div> <!--/ .container -->

    </section>
    <!--
    =======================
    ==/ END HERO SECTION ==
    =======================
    --></div><!-- /#page -->

  <!-- Load JS here for greater good =============================-->
     <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

     <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- SmoothScroll -->
  <script src="js/minified/SmoothScroll.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Classie -->
  <script src="js/minified/classie.min.js"></script>

  <!-- One Page Nav -->
  <script src="js/minified/jquery.nav.min.js"></script>

  <!-- AjaxChimp -->
  <script src="js/minified/jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Swipebox -->
  <script src="js/minified/jquery.swipebox.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Expandable Gallery on 2 Block Column -->
  <script src="js/minified/expandableGallery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Counter Up -->
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/2.0.3/waypoints.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/minified/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Isotope JS -->
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/isotope-layout@3.0/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/urip-isotope-setting.js"></script>

  <!-- Stellar JS -->
  <script src="js/jquery.stellar.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom JS -->
  <script src="js/urip-v2.js"></script>

  <!-- Expandable Navigation Menu -->
  <script src="js/minified/expandableNav.min.js"></script>

 

</body></html>
```

Comment: Your original post was never closed. There is no need to post this again.

Comment: have you checked your error_log?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
header('Location: redirectpage.php');
header('Location: redirectpage.php');exit();
echo "<script>location.href='redirectpage.php';</script>";
?>
```

Probably your header is already set by the time you are trying to modify it.